# Testing multiple URLs in Cypress and 'ignoring' failures

Tags: javascript, automation, cypress

I'm testing a component that appears on many pages of a WEB site, so I created a script that passes by each one. It works, but if a failure happens on some URL the test stops, and the script doesn't move on to the other URLs.

I'm using a file .json within the Fixture folder that contains an array with some URLs.

```
[
    {"url":"www.example01.com"},
    {"url":"www.example02.com"},
    {"url":"www.example03.com"},
    {"url":"www.example04.com"}
]
```

I'm using this script below for run a test on each URL.

```
/// <reference types="cypress"/>

const urlTest = require('../../fixtures/URLs.json')
const estado = 'São Paulo'
const municipio = 'SAO PAULO'

describe('Test de url', () => {
    it(`Visit URL and check the resseler component`, () => {
        cy.get(urlTest).each((param) => {
         cy.visit(param.url)
         cy.welcomeBannerAndCookiesAcceptation()

         cy.intercept('POST', '**/WhereToBuyResult').as('searchResultState')
         cy.intercept('POST', '**/CitiesReSellers').as('searchResultTown')
            
         cy.validateMunicipioFieldIsAvailable() 
    
         cy.getState(estado) 

         cy.wait('@searchResultTown')
    
         cy.getTown(municipio) 
    
         cy.wait('@searchResultState')
    
         cy.validateIfResselersAreVisible() 
     });
        
 })
})
```

I'm seeking a solution that keeps testing the component on each URL regardless of whether a fail was found or not, and indicates which URLs have presented failures.

**Cypress: v10.9.0**

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you move the loop _outside_ the test, if you want them to be separate?

Comment: If it is a component you are testing, shouldn't this be a component test?

Answer (score 1):

This will give independent tests, so if one fails the others still run.

```js
/// <reference types="cypress"/>

const urlTests = require('../../fixtures/URLs.json')

describe('Test de url', () => {

  urlTests.forEach(URL => {

    it(`Visit "${url}" and check the resseler component`, () => {
      cy.visit(url)
      ...
    })
  })
})
```